# Some parts of TextViews don't show and are cut off by the edge of the screen

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, tablerow, android-tablelayout

[image]

I have a query results from a database and corresponding variables are filled.
I think that the problem is the layout, I am using incorrect layouts in my XML file. Maybe it is the `ArrayAdapter`, I don't know. I've spent a lot of hours trying to solve this problem and haven't been able to. Thanks for your help!

This is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<TableRow>        
    <TextView android:id="@+id/precio_offers_charger"            
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20px"     
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"        
        android:background="#FF0000" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/cabecera_offers_charger"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="18px"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:background="#010201" />                 
</TableRow>  

<TableRow>
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imagen"        
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/descripcion_offers_charger"
        android:paddingLeft="10px"
        android:paddingTop="10px"           
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="14px" />                                      
</TableRow>     

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"        
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>

</TableLayout>
```

---

This is a part of my class:

```
public class OffersChargerActivity extends ListActivity{                    

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);     
    setContentView(R.layout.offers_charger);

... 


public class AdaptadorTitulares extends ArrayAdapter<Oferta> {

    Activity context;

    AdaptadorTitulares(Activity context) {
        super(context, R.layout.offers_charger, ofertas);
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null) {
            LayoutInflater linflater = (LayoutInflater)   getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = linflater.inflate(R.layout.offers_charger, null);
        }                   

        // poblamos la lista de elementos           
        TextView precio = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.precio_offers_charger);
        precio.setText(ofertas.get(position).getPrecio().concat("€"));

        ImageView imagen = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imagen);
        imagen.setImageBitmap(new GetImages().downloadFile(ofertas.get(position).getImagen()));

        TextView cabecera = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.cabecera_offers_charger);
        cabecera.setText(ofertas.get(position).getCabecera());

        TextView descripcion = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.descripcion_offers_charger);
        descripcion.setText(ofertas.get(position).getDescripcion());                                                

        return view;
    }                       
}   

...
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
   <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
```

Try adding in 'layout_weight' and change your 'layout_width' to "fill_parent".

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

don't wrap content, use fill_parent for width, and also set android:ellipsize="true"

Comment: What I just said. 'android:ellipsize="true"' is not needed either.

Comment: by saying 'either' are you implying the first part wasn't needed as well?

Comment: Nope. I'm pretty sure making it 'fill_parent' is what fixes it. Hence why that was my answer...

Comment: fill_parent fixes the text cut-off. ellipsize fixes long-word cut-off.
imagine if the whole text is a string. without ellipsize it won't wrap properly. though i could settle on "it's a useless property" if i'm wrong :)

Comment: I don't have ellipsize and even without it, the text drops down to the next line. This doesn't change whether it is multiple words or one long word. I just tested it on my app. :)

Comment: great, i guess that makes it a useless property then :) makes one wonder why its even there. unless .... you know... on some devices it's a required one.

Comment: Can you clarify more, what you mean? Just so I know I've got it right. Surely you never want it to have ellipsizes because you usually always want the user to be able to see all the text? That's just my opinion.

Comment: ..... in case ellipsizes are those dots that shorten stuff then yeah. honest mistake :)

Comment: Yeah they are the three dots to shorten items. It's up to you, however I just don't like using them because I always want my app users to see everything. No mistake made, personal choice! :)

Comment: no, i really thought it was for breaking up words, it was kind of a lingual mistake...

Comment: Oh haha fair enough. Yeah it automatically puts the words onto the next line. So it does look fine, to be honest. However a '-' could be used as they use that symbol when it goes onto the next line, although I haven't done this and am not sure how you do it either. This is if you want to be extra picky. :P

Comment: yea, i was thinking about hyphenation (?) and that's when you cut off a long word with a hyphen (-). i 'internally' translated it wrongly into my language :) but i still think i used it for just that and not hiding text. oh wll, live and learn.

Comment: Yeah that's right, it's hyphenation. I'm not sure how to do it in Android. I'm sure it's easy enough, but I'm not bothered about it. Nice English!